# Which hardware router(s) support directing all web traffic through an external proxy server?

Tags: proxy, router, squid

I have a SQUID proxy server running on an external machine that I would like all web traffic on my network to go through.  My goal is to find a router (hardware) that allows me to specify the default gateway address all the DHCP clients get (the address to my external proxy server).

My cheap linksys WRT54G does not support this.  Which (hardware) routers do?  I do not want to use a PC as my router.

Thank you

Comment: Have you considered setting up wpad and blocking http/https connections that are not directed at the proxy server?

Comment: want to do it at the router level

Answer (score 2):

You can change the firmware of your router to a 3rd party DD-WRT.

It offers more functions and it will allow you to choose a default gateway on your DHCP server.

DD-WRT: [Linksys WRT54G](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Linksys_WRT54G/GL/GS/GX)

Comment: Thanks, Roy.  I did see that while searching and the installation process scared the hell out of me.  May try it out anyway, though.

Answer (score 2):

It's looking like there are 3 routers that play very nicely with DD-WRT, the software that supports the external proxy server.  Mine is not one of them, but they are:

## BUFFALO WHR-HP-G54

## LINKSYS WRT54GL

## ASUS WL-500g

All about $60-70 ... not bad.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much about these low-end/consumer routers but I'd be surprised if you can't dictate the DG for your DHCP clients, I've certainly never come across a router/DHCP-server that can't. Are you sure it's not hidden away somewhere in a distant menu?

edit - actually I just read the manual, you're right, it doesn't - that sucks, I'll try to find you something. Worst comes to worst you could always setup a cheapo PC to be your DHCP server.

Comment: yeah, this crap linksys doesn't allow you to change DG for the DHCP clients - i've been through the menus and on the forums about it.  Surely better routers allow it ... just trying to figure out which ones.  thx ..

Comment: thank man. i'm trying to find off-the-shelf hardware for this for a variety of reasons ... hopefully i can find one that supports it.

Comment: one quick question, do you need it to be a DSL modem too?

Comment: nope, the router is plugging into a Comcast cable modem.  all this thing has to do is assign DHCP (with my custom default gateway) to LAN and WIRELESS.  It can take its own IP/DNS/DG from the cable router's DHCP server.

Comment: You could very easily just stick in any old PC to act as a, highly-configurable, DHCP server - keeping your existing router where it is. It's that or buying a much more expensive router for just this single function. A netbook would do the job.

Answer (score 0):

> I have a SQUID proxy server running on an external machine

Does that mean that the proxy is on a different subnet than your clients? If so then setting the proxy server as a default gateway will prevent them from actually reaching the proxy. The clients will simply have no way of knowing how to reach it.

Also remember that Squid is a http proxy - it doesn't handle other protocols (DNS, mail, Skype, etc.) so directing all traffic to it would fail.

If you wish to force all *http* traffic to go via. the proxy then you need to look into the NAT and firewall settings of your router and set it to direct all traffic on port 80 via. your proxy.